# What is wrong in my ajax url?

Tags: javascript, cart, controllers, url, ajax

I have written the following code

the js

```
$.ajax({
    showLoader: true,
    cache: false,
    url: url.build('multiplecustomer/account/Logout'),
    type: "POST",
  }).done(function (data) {
    console.log("data is "+data);
   });
   this.closeModal();
}
```

the controller path

**Vendor\MultipleCustomer\Controller\Account\Logout.php;**

My controller code

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\MultipleCustomer\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Logout extends Action
{
  protected  $modelCart;
  protected $checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        Session $checkoutSession,
        Cart $modelCart
        )
    {
      $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
      $this->modelCart = $modelCart;
      parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/controllerlogout.log');
        $logger = new \Zend_Log();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info("l26 in logout ");
        $cart = $this->modelCart;
        $quoteItems = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
        foreach($quoteItems as $item)
        {
            $cart->removeItem($item->getId())->save();
        }
        $logger->info("l36 in logout ");
    }
}
?>
```

but the controller file is not getting called. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try with lower L -> multiplecustomer/account/logout

Comment: What name is in routes.xml ?

Comment: I tried using lower l too... it didn't work

Comment: here is my routes.xml          
        <route id="multicustomer" frontName="multicustomer">

Comment: Vyacheslav Shmal... your comment helped. the frontName is actually wrong. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Please try it like this.
So you should to call 'mage/url' to use URL build.

```
define([
    "jquery",
    'mage/url'
], function($, urlBuilder){
    'use strict';
     
     ...
     var url = urlBuilder.build('multiplecustomer/account/Logout');
     ...
```

Comment: yes  I was using this.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your controller only react to get methods, it needs to extend HttpPostInterface one. Can you provide your controller code to make sure of it ?

Comment: I have added the controller code. kindly check

Comment: As i said, i'm suggesting you to implement this one `use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;`

Comment: Claims...the code is working fine without that too. now the controller is getting called.